# Refactoring Express and SocketIO app

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

I realise there are similar questions on SO but I can't find one that helps me. I have an Expressjs 4 app and I'm using SocketIO too. A snippet of my `server.js` file looks like this:

```
// server.js
...
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app).listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

var routesApi = require('./server/routes/api');

module.exports = app;
```

and I have `api.js`:

```
// server/routes/api.js
...
var ctrlPosts = require('../controllers/posts');
router.post('/posts', ctrlPosts.create);
...
```

and my posts controller:

```
// controllers/posts
module.exports.create = function(req, res) {
  //how can I access io from here?
}
```

**Question**
How can I access SocketIO from my posts controller?

Answer (score 1):

You can design your posts controller to accept parameter in constructor.

```
var controller = function(server){
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);
    var module = {
        create : function(req, res) {...}
    }
    return module;
}
```

Similar to this, you can design your routes api to accept server parameter and call posts controller like this:

```
var api = function(server){
    var ctrlPosts = require('../controllers/posts')(server);
}
```

and require api like this:

```
var routesApi = require('./server/routes/api')(server);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful - I passed `io` from the `server.js` to the `api.js` file and then on to the posts controller.

Answer (score 1):

Create a socket.js in config directory and export io

```
// socket.js
var socketio = require('socket.io')

module.exports.listen = function(app){
    io = socketio.listen(app)

    posts = io.of('/posts')
    posts.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.on ...
    })

    return io
}
```

and then call it in your controller

```
// controller
var io = require('./config/socket').listen(app)
```